# Advantages and disadvantages of using ID selectors in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

[This post](http://screwlewse.com/2010/07/dont-use-id-selectors-in-css/) talked about the disadvantage about using ID selectors in CSS. Do you more about the advantages and disadvantages about using ID selectors in CSS? When should I use ID selectors and when should I use class selectors? Thanks.

Comment: If there is only ever one, use ID. If there may possibly be more than one, use class. Duh.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a free discussion forum. If you want to ask this question in a specific context then that's fine. If you want to discuss 'this post' then I see plenty of scope for that on the original blog.

Comment: Having read that post, I have to wonder why they seem to think (my inferrence from what is said) that a class used once is somehow better than an ID...

Comment: CSS is still young in my opinion, when structured code becomes an even bigger part of css, it will clean out the bad code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id selector is used to specify a style for a single, unique element.

The id selector uses the id attribute of the HTML element, and is defined with a "#".

The style rule below will be applied to the element with id="para1":

```
#para1
{
text-align:center;
color:red;
}
```

Reference : [Ref](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp)

It simply identifies one instance for an ID, a class will be inherit in the overall website, higher lvls of importance.

Answer (score 0):

IDs have a higher level of specificity than classes in CSS. This helps to create strong reference points for children selectors. They're faster and easier to identify in the DOM versus a class.

Although, this really means nothing! ID's and classes are more abstract concepts than anything. General rule:

> Multiple Elements - Class
>   Element Singleton - ID

Does it really matter? Not really.

Comment: It matters to some, good structured css is a beautiful thing compared to a "it doesnt matter" css file.

Comment: Well, it matters in a theoretical sense, but in practicality the difference is too miniscule to have any real impact.

Comment: It has an impact when you are trying to MAINTAIN code. I recommend you consider how valuable your work is!

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but my comment was towards the pros/cons debate rather than standard usage.

Comment: David, you have to respect the rules of css, although its a very creative area, there are classes id's and other references in css for a VERY good reason, In css its a structured language. In ALL languages and css is very much a language.

Comment: I'm speaking from a performance basis. Sure, it's good practice but when you delve deep into the DOM you realize that the words "class" and "id" in css is just merely syntactic sugar.

Comment: surely when you delve deeper it becomes more important to have order, also i dont think you respect the fact that more than 1 person can work on your code. "just merely syntactic sugar" How incorrect.. I hate to keep going on about it but if you dont follow standards you don't allow the progress of how the CREATORS of the language want the language to go.

Comment: I actually appreciate the criticisms, but the point I am making is that there is only a CONCEPTUAL difference between the two. I do believe in following the standards, but only on a completely organizational basis (maintainability).

Comment: Yes David, you are correct, and indeed by that standard you are free to do as you wish much the same you can write style="bla bla" directly into a div.. Its not good to teach our bad habbits! :) Keep up the work!